# CSS background-image doesn't work

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a problem to visualize (in all browsers) the background-image that I use in the CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:-5px;">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="box1" style="width:311px; float:left;">
                <div class="markermenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.markermenu{
    width: 311px; /*width of menu*/
}

.markermenu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 1px 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #9A9A9A;
}

.markermenu ul li a{
    background:url(img/lens.png) no-repeat 2px center;
    height:79px;
    color: #00014e;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 30px 0;
    padding-left: 90px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B5B5B5;
}

* html .markermenu ul li a{ 
    width: 150px;
}

.markermenu ul li a:visited, .markermenu ul li a:active{
    color: #00014e;
}

.markermenu ul li a:hover{
    color: black;
    background-color: #ffffcb;
    background-image:url(img/icon/arrow.png); 
    z-index:10;/*onMouseover image change. Remove if none*/
}
```

The problem is that I don't see the images on background...someone know why..?
Thanks so much.

Resolved. Thanks!!! Another question...if i wont use a different image for avery voice of the menu (normal and hover) AND if i wont use two image for every voice, how i must modify the html and css??? thanks so much

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Have you checked you paths? And the console for errors?

Comment: `background-image:url('the path to your image');` or `background-image:url(the path to your image);`

Comment: to be sure, you can try commenting out all the on-top elements and see if the background is shown, if not, maybe the path is wrong or simply there is not any image available.

Comment: try this  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image . In your case, the path to image is probably wrong

Comment: guys, why do we need a jsfiddle for this. He cannot create a fiddle with his actual location of image, so no way can we test the background image. Only thing is he should check the relative path of the image, that he is passing as parameter. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: make sure the subdirectory "img" is right UNDER the directory where the CSS file is located, so if style.css is located at `root/css`, `img` should be at `root/css/img` otherwise use absolute paths

Comment: I have edited the answer with another question, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to check the path of the background-image in the

```
.markermenu ul li a { }
```

and

```
.markermenu ul li a: hover { }
```

classes.

If you have provided the path correctly then your code should work fine. See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qy2T2/

Comment: Resolved. Thanks!!! Another question...if i wont use two different image for avery voice of the menu (normal and hover), once on the left (an now) and once on the right of the menu voice, how i must modify the html and css??? thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

### Background - Shorthand Property

#### Format:

```
background: <color> url("<image path>") <repeat> <x> <y>;
```

#### Example:

```
body { background: #FFFFFF url("MyImage.png") no-repeat right top; }
```

<kbd>[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XB3s9/)</kbd>

Make sure you check your image path.